# How to design layouts with dynamic content in ADT/GraphicalLayout?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, adt

We used to work with a lot of dynamic content in layouts, from frame layouts and fragments to buttons, images and textviews that we finally inflate, fill in with content and append them in execution time. To do that I like to design little resources parts to define its common style so I can re-use them later programatically.

**The problem**: I end up with all the layout resource elements represented as a white screen when you open them in the ADT Graphical Layout, due to all the elements are empty ready to receive their content.

Is there a better way to deal with layouts?

Am I doing it wrong because I have always to use CustomViews to encapsulate those little parts to work with isInEditMode?

I couldn't find any good practices guide about how to design elements for dynamic content.

---

**Example**: a list item view

*What you see*

[image]

---

*The truth behind*

[image]
[image]

I used to fill the elements with fake content to visualize them in order to adjust the final style, but I wonder if there is a better solution..

Comment: ListViews , GridViews, ViewPagers - > look into this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html

Comment: can you elaborate on the "dynamic view" definition ?

Comment: Imagine for example some kind of menubar with textviews, imagebuttons,  etc that every activity or fragment use it with their own buttons/actions. So you define an empty layout with the menubar style and a resource representing one of this complex-buttons as a template. Finally, programatically, every activity clear de menubar-layout, build all his buttons from the template and insert them into the menubar-layout. All that happens when the app is running, so you can't see how your app look like from the ADT designer tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this:  [tools attribute](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes)
And this: [Layout design time attributes](http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes)

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for.
It seems that 'designtime layout attributes' don't work on Eclipse/ADT, right?